# How to setup OpenCL correctly?

Tags: c, opencl

### Specs

- Windows 10 64 bit
- Intel Core i7
- Amd Radeon R9
- GCC 6.8.0 from mingw

### Setup

I downloaded OpenCL from here : https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-opencl/download. I tried AMD for OpenCL first, but all the pages I tried have said "404 page not found".

This is the code I am testing OpenCL with.

### opencl.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <CL/cl.h>

int main() {
    cl_device_id device_id;
    cl_uint num_devices;

    cl_int id = clGetDeviceIDs(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, &device_id, &num_devices);

    return 0;
}
```

I tried compiling this code with.

```
gcc opencl.c -I C:\Intel\OpenCL\sdk\include -L C:\Intel\OpenCL\sdk\lib\x64 -o opencl.exe
```

But I get this error.

```
undefined reference to `clGetDeviceIDs@24'
```

If I remove the line with the clGetDeviceIDs function it compiles fine.

### -lOpenCL

I've also tried compiling with,

```
gcc opencl.c -I C:\Intel\OpenCL\sdk\include -lOpenCL -o opencl.exe
```

but it says...

```
cannot find -lOpenCL
```

I read somewhere that -lOpenCL is made when you download the OpenCL drivers. So I tried downloading the driver here : https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/OpenCL2-Driver.aspx. I installed the driver and then ran the setup but it said it doesn't detect any AMD graphics hardware.

### Edit

I changed `-L C:\Intel\OpenCL\sdk\lib\x64` to `-L C:\Intel\OpenCL\sdk\lib\x86` and compiled with
`gcc opencl.c -I C:\Intel\OpenCL\sdk\include -L C:\Intel\OpenCL\sdk\lib\x86 -lOpenCL -o opencl.exe` and it worked? So I check my system settings to make sure I have Windows 64 bit and it says
`64-bit operating system, x64-based processor`. So did I install the wrong version of OpenCL?

Comment: What happens if you try compiling like this: `gcc opencl.c -I C:\Intel\OpenCL\sdk\include -L C:\Intel\OpenCL\sdk\lib\x64 -lOpenCL -o opencl.exe`?

Comment: @Xirema I just tried what you suggested and the error saying `cannot find -lOpenCL` goes away, but the error `undefined reference to \`clGetDeviceIDs@24'` appears again.

Comment: Does `C:\Intel\OpenCL\sdk\lib\x64` contain the `.lib` file that you need to use to link to your executable? If it does, what is it called?

Comment: @Xirema It does its called `OpenCL.lib`.

Answer (score 1):

The choice of whether to use the 32-bit binary (x86) or the 64-bit binary (x64) is based on the *target* architecture of your application, not the architecture of the computer compiling the program. The reason the x86 version of the library worked and the x64 version didn't is that your *compiler* is compiling in 32-bit mode. Switch to compiling in x64 to get the x64 library to link properly.

I'm not incredibly familiar with gcc, so I don't know what flags control that behavior. Check your compiler documentation. Note that whether the compiler itself is 32-bit or 64-bit should be irrelevant.